# Prove: $\int_{X}(\varphi+\psi)d \mu =\int_{X}\varphi d \mu +\int_{X}\psi d \mu$

Tags: measure-theory

$$\int_{X}(\varphi+\psi)d \mu =\int_{X}\varphi d \mu +\int_{X}\psi d \mu$$

Proof: We will write the stand definition of the simple functions $\psi=\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_fI_{F_j}$ and $\varphi=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kI_{E_k}$ because $E_k$ and $F_j$ are pairwise disjoint so does $E_k\cap F_j$ and for $E_k\cap F_j$ we have that $\varphi(x)=a_k$ and $\psi(x)=b_j$ and $(\varphi+psi)(x)=a_k+b_j$ therefore:
$$\int_{X}(\varphi+\psi)d \mu =\sum_{j,k}(a_k+b_j)\mu (E_k\cap F_j)=\sum_{j,k}a_k\mu (E_k\cap F_j)+\sum_{j,k}b_j\mu (E_k\cap F_j)=\int_{X}\varphi d \mu+\int_{X}\psi d \mu$$

This is a proof from a lecture notes, why can we be sure that "$E_k$ and $F_j$ are pairwise disjoint"? we can create them? is the stand definition of the simple function defined on disjoint set $E_k$?

Comment: @drhab So we basically create this disjoint partition, it is not given "for free" from the definition of stand definition of the simple function?

Comment: Yes, you create this partition (see my answer). Be aware though that this is not the only possible expression for $\phi$ (which justifies your questioning). See it as a canonical way to write a simple function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read: "because the $E_k$ are pairwise disjoint and the $F_j$ are pairwise disjoint so are the $E_k\cap F_j$ pairwise disjoint...."

If $(k\neq k')\implies E_k\cap E_{k'}=\varnothing$ and $(j\neq j')\implies F_j\cap F_{j'}=\varnothing$ then it is not difficult to deduce that:
$$(k,j)\neq(k',j')\implies (E_k\cap F_j)\cap(E_{k'}\cap F_{j'})=\varnothing$$and that is the issue here.

If $\phi$ is a simple function then its image $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ is finite.

Indexing $I$ as $I=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ where the $a_i$ are distinct we can go for:  $$E_k:=\{x\mid \phi(x)=a_k\}$$

These sets form a partition of the domain of $\phi$ and we can write:$$\phi=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\mathbf1_{E_k}$$